Where can I find a list of reserved keyword for named attribute ? (geometry Node)
I found out by mistake that you can use the "store named attribute" node to override values of some attribute. Like "position" for example (why would someone wants to do that ?). I was remapping coordinate for a texture to stretch along a curve and used the name "uv" when I saw that using Cycles won't work but EEVEE will (pic below). Took me some time to figure out that the problem was the name of the attribute. Anyway know that I understand it's not that much of an issue but I was really confused, I expected at least a warning for using reserved keyword. So out of curiosity I'm looking for a list of all reserved keywords.
I found some here :
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#built-in-attributes
But it's not complete. (for example at least "uv" is missing).
So does anyone knows where I can find a complete list of reserved keyword for named attribute that could lead to unexpected behavior ?


There's a full list of the ones not visible in the attribute panel here:
what can you call from the attribute node?
Also, you can input custom property names or RNA paths for the "Object" and "View Layer" dropdown options on the Attribute Node to get their property values, as mentioned here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html
Finally, there are the visible ones in the attribute panel, as mentioned here;
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html
